# CacheMinutesInterval dbprovider not working

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the DBProvider with Url Rewrite Module and have caching turned on but sql profiler tells me the cache isn't working at all. Here is my configuration setting.

```
<provider name="FileMap" type="DbProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f">
  <settings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=IP;database=DBNAME;uid=sa;pwd=PASS;"/>
    <add key="StoredProcedure" value="Search.GetRewriteUrl"/>
    <add key="CacheMinutesInterval" value="10"/>
  </settings>
</provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching is working fine. I didn't have to change anything. I made better filtering on my SQL Profiler and noticed that caching is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Bok Ogi,

Outbound rules are not cached, so you will see this manifested by having the stored proc hit every time the rule is invoked.  Only Inbound rules are cached.

Comment: Hello Radomir, thank you for you quick answer. I'm using only inbound rules. Everything is working fine. I just misinterpreted SQL profiler report.